# Creating percentages for each group using dply

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

So I have a df as follows

```
df <- structure(list(Reportable = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA), 
    Stakeholder = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "1", "3", "4", "5", "5"
    ), count = c(68L, 154L, 241L, 132L, 309L, 203L, 403L, 215L, 
    1L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(FRA.Reportable = c(0, 
1, NA), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want to create a new var called `pct` which shows the percentage of each group within the group. So When Stakeholder = 1, both the 0 and 1 in Reportable should sum to 100%. I try this with the following but this does not calculate correctly

```
df %>%
  mutate(pct = percent(count/sum(count)))
```

So basically all entries within a given Stakeholder should sum to 100%.

This will eventually be used here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=as.factor(Reportable), y=count, x=as.factor(Stakeholder), label = pct)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  labs(x = "Stakeholder", y = "Count")+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dplyr::group_by`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Stakeholder) %>% 
  mutate(pct = count/sum(count))
```

Returns

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Stakeholder [4]
  Reportable Stakeholder count     pct
       <dbl> <chr>       <int>   <dbl>
1          0 1              68 0.180  
2          0 3             154 0.431  
3          0 4             241 0.374  
4          0 5             132 0.379  
5          1 1             309 0.820  
6          1 3             203 0.569  
7          1 4             403 0.626  
8          1 5             215 0.618  
9         NA 5               1 0.00287
```